# How to change resolution ratio in RTCCameraVideoCapturer

Tags: ios, camera, webrtc

How can I change the resolution ratio in RTCCameraVideoCapturer? 
I choose a AVCaptureDevice.Format, and the resolution ratio is 1280*720. I want to preview it on a fullfill screen view. How can I change the resolution ratio 1280*720 into 1334*750. Should I zoom or something else?

Comment: if this is similar to `getUserMedia()`, there would be video constraints containing `width`, `height` and `aspectRatio`.

Comment: Thanks,but the constraints has deprecated in m66 version. [issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7177)  , it seems that I have to make some scale instead of using constraints.

Comment: An alternative can be using a canvas